# Graphing Multiple Initial Conditions

Tags: plotting

So I have this system of equations that I've solved by hand, but want to graph with multiple initial conditions.
But I don't want to have mutiple spamming lines of code like this.

```
graph1a = ContourPlot[{y^3 == x^3}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
graph2a = ContourPlot[{y^3 == x^3 + 2}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
graph3a = ContourPlot[{y^3 == x^3 - 2}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
graph4a = ContourPlot[{y^3 == x^3 + 15}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
graph5a = ContourPlot[{y^3 == x^3 - 15}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]; 
graph6a = ContourPlot[{y^3 == x^3 + 75}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
graph7a = ContourPlot[{y^3 == x^3 - 75}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
Show[graph1a, graph2a, graph3a, graph4a, graph5a, graph6a, graph7a]
```

I'm pretty sure there's a way to nicely put this into fewer lines.
The Equation solution is

```
y^3 = x^3 + K
```

with $K$ being the initial condition.

Comment: that would be enough: `ContourPlot[{y^3 == x^3 + {0, 2, -2, 15, -15, 75, -75}}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to plot are simply some contour lines of a single function, $y^3-x^3$, so there is no need to to `Show` many graphics overlapped, all the tools are provided by `ContourPlot` itself:

```
ContourPlot[y^3 - x^3, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 Contours -> {0, 2, -2, 15, -15, 75, -75},
 ContourShading -> None,
 ContourLabels -> True,
 ContourStyle -> Gray
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you prefer some colors, you can replace the last option with something like `ContourStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"]`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is how I'd have done it. :) +1

Answer (score 4):

```
Show@
  Table[
    ContourPlot[{y^3 == x^3 + const}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}],
    {const, {0, 2, -2, 15, -15, 75, -75}}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively,

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[Table[y^3 == x^3 + k, {k, {0, 2, -2, 15, -15, 75, -75}}]], {x, -10, 
  10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Or if you want to augment existing `Tooltip`

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[Table[y^3 == x^3 + k, {k, {0, 2, -2, 15, -15, 75, -75}}]], {x, -10, 
  10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Why is there __Evaluate__ function in the argument for ContourPlot?

Comment: @SmartHumanism - remove the `Evaluate` and compare the results. Then look at the `Attributes` for `ContourPlot`.